# Google Analytics - scheduled emails

Tags: google, google-analytics

I've setup a scheduled email report for Google Analytics to an email group. I've recently changed the email group that the report goes to and it doesn't seem to be sending to that email, at least not within the last 60 minutes.

The email group works fine as I sent a test email to it and everyone received it.

I previously had issues with the last email group I was sending the report to as it would send the report at completely random times. Sometimes in the evening other times in the morning and sometimes not at all!

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue and would know why it's doing this/ have a potential fix?

Answer (score 1):

There should not be an issue with this. Should be as straightforward as just dropping in an email.

So your issues are either with the email group set up or with the report.

**The Test**

Send this report to your own email address, preferably one on a different domain. This will determine if its something with the email group set up or the report.